# Update the preview text in a URL shared on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

So we have this client with a Facebook page (currently unpublished).
They have shared hundreds of links to their website on their wall over the last few years. The problem is that the preview text on most (if not all) of them is now out of date.

I have looked over similar issues on here and have seen that most things suggest going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, putting in the URL and that clears Facebook's cache.

So I tried this on a couple of the links, and the info that the debugger gets me is correct, but this doesn't update the links on the Facebook wall. The question is this: is there a way to get Facebook to refresh these *already posted* link descriptions, or do I have to go through them all manually reposting hundreds of links?

I hope you can help!

Comment: AFAIK already existing posts are not updated – think about it, would you like to post a link to your timeline that has something cute about kittens in the description, and a few weeks later it changes to how wonderful v14gr4 is …? No, of course not.

Comment: @CBroe I thought this was the case, but wanted to check incase anyone knew of a way to force an update, so someone doesn't have to spend hours re-posting :)